# Apply a math function on all integers value of two strings

Tags: c#

Two strings are given. I want to apply a math function on each number in the strings and save  it in new string. Rules:

```
"19834675"; // keypc
"28374651";// keyserial
(1)sb[0]=max(keypc[0],keyserial[0])  the first element of final string
    max(1,2)=2   1 is first of"19834675" , 2 is first of "28374651"
(2)sb[1]=Math.Floor((keypc[1]+keyserial[1])/3) the second element of final string  // 
(3)sb[2]= (keypc[1]+keyserial[1]) The remainder is divided by 10 
8+3=11---->1 , 8 is the third char of "19834675" and 3  the third char of "28374651"
```

My try for (1):

I used the following code for (1)

```
  string keypc    ="19834675";
  string keyserial="28374651";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(keypc,keypc.Length);
 if (sbkeypc[0] < sbkeyserial[0])
 {
            sb[0] = sbkeyserial[0];
     }else
        {
            sb[0] = sbkeypc[0];
    }
```

My try for (2):The question is why the following code does not work?!
and How to do (3)?

```
   double inttemp=Math.Floor((Char.GetNumericValue(keypc[1])+Char.GetNumericValue(keyserial[1]))/3);
   sb[1]= Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(inttemp));
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(inttemp))); // error here --->return ""
   Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // error here: the length of sb reduced
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your question?

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are keypc, keyserial ? The 2 given strings ? You are only using the first 2 characters of these strings, is that correct ? Where does 8 + 3 come from, these are the third characters. Remainder of what is divided by 10 ?

Comment: "keypc" created from bios and cpu information. "keyserial" is the key on the product. The  practice is create a new string  from the two string "keypc" and "keyserial". Sorry for the unclear explanation.

Comment: I used just 3 index  just for avoid long question.

Comment: @Martin Verjans, 8 is the third char of "19834675" and 3  the third char of "28374651". 8+3=11, the remain by dividing by 10 for example 11--->1 ,  23--->3 , 4--->4, 18---->8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

You can see it in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q75r5d)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string keypc = "19834675";
        string keyserial = "28374651";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(keypc, keypc.Length);
        sb[0] = MinChar(keypc[0], keyserial[0]);
        sb[1] = FloorChar(keypc[1], keyserial[1]);
        for (int i=2; i<keypc.Length; i++)
        {
            sb[i] = RemainderChar(keypc[i], keyserial[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static char MinChar(char c1, char c2)
    {
        double val1 = Char.GetNumericValue(c1);
        double val2 = Char.GetNumericValue(c2);
        double val3 = Math.Min(val1, val2);
        string str = val3.ToString();
        return str[0];
    }

    public static char FloorChar(char c1, char c2)
    {
        double val1 = Char.GetNumericValue(c1);
        double val2 = Char.GetNumericValue(c2);
        double val3 = Math.Floor((val1+val2)/3);
        string str = val3.ToString();
        return str[0];
    }

    public static char RemainderChar(char c1, char c2)
    {
        double val1 = Char.GetNumericValue(c1);
        double val2 = Char.GetNumericValue(c2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", val1, val2);
        double val3 = (val1+val2) % 10;
        Console.WriteLine("" + val3);
        string str = val3.ToString();
        return str[0];
    }
}
```